# swift - animate annotation changes

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a mapView with multiple annotations with custom images displayed on it. using `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

currently have this code to change the size of the image if the annotation is selected or deselected:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    view.frame = CGRect(x: (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!, y: (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!, width: 50, height: 50)

}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   //code to return it to normal annotation size

    view.frame = CGRect(x: (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!, y: (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!, width: 30, height: 30)

}
```

This works fine, However I would like to animate the change as it would look better. When I add animation code like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: (view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!, y: (view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!, width: 30, height: 30)
})
```

the animation has the annotation slide in diagonally from off screen. I have tried switching x: and y: or just setting them to 0 but neither seems to work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can animate the `transform` instead.

Comment: you can try scaling the size of your annotation view with transformation

Answer (score 1):

Adding the code I ended up using for anyone else having a similar issu. Thank you to [Mannopson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680583/mannopson) and [Ashwin Shrestha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9130596/ashwin-shrestha)

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
})
```